# null field in database shows up as null string in angularjs html

Tags: angularjs

I am working with AngularJS and there are few fields which are of text type.

```
<input value="" placeholder="" type="text" ng-disabled= "!obj.enableEdit" ng-model="obj.example"/>
```

The field obj.example is saved as null (which is a requirement to save as null if there is no value). When the null value from database shows up in text field it shows "null" string in the field.

There are couple of fields like this so I do not think I should do a null check in controller.

Any suggestions how can I resolve it?

Thanks!

Comment: create an if statement in your controller or ng-init in your html and set obj.example = "" if obj.example is set to null

Comment: Hey @Mat, there are like 5-6 fields like this and obj is an object in array so there will be lot of if checks in the controller. I am looking for if we can do something on the html itself or if I am missing something.

Comment: @jsmtslch I just tested with Plunker and it does not seem to show null as string. See [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/GDLsEBHOpFASrcGjI9oV?p=preview). Are you sure your backend does not interpret null as "null" string?

Comment: @potato i checked at the backend that due to some code change the values are getting saved as null string. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @potato suggested I checked the database with DBA and the values were coming up as null string. Thanks, @potato

Answer (score 0):

few ways to fix:

1. compare explicitly with "null" string in ng-disabled
2. When you retrieve the object, check for "null" string in the controller and either replace the value with a boolean or else stick another boolean variable in your response. Then use that boolean in ng-disabled.